# If the Option Value is having value="0" alert true

Tags: javascript, jquery

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/47bjej9s/)

**HTML:**

```html
<select>
    <option value="0">this is 0 </option>
    <option value="1">this is 1 </option>
    <option value="2">this is 2 </option>
    <option value="3">this is 3 </option>
</select>
```

**JS**:

```js
$(function () {
    if ( $("select option[value='0']") == option[value='0'] ) {
        alert('asd')
    }
})
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: If the Option Value is having value="0" , then alert

Comment: If you want to set value use `$("select").val(0)`

Answer (score 1):

```
 <select id='mySelect'>
```

JS:

```
var  selectedValue=document.getElementById('mySelect').value;
if(selectedValue=='0')
alert('asd');
```

Comment: how to select from  class ?

Comment: <select class='mySelect'> ..easier way would be to use jquery then..like this ->  var value=(".mySelect").val();

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this.

```
<select >
    <option value="0">this is 0 </option>
    <option value="1">this is 1 </option>
    <option value="2">this is 2 </option>
    <option value="3">this is 3 </option>
</select>

$(function (){
    var value = $("select option:selected").val();
    if( value  == '0' ) {
        alert('asd')
    }
})
```

Check Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/47bjej9s/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("select").on('change',function(){
            if($(this).val()==0)
            {
                alert('success');
            }
        })
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Give id to your select tag:

```
<select id="selectBox">
```

and

```
$(function (){

    if( $("#selectBox").val()  == 0 ) {   //change here
        alert('asd');
    }
});
```